# PHP execute script with --ansi as default

Tags: php, linux, symfony

When I execute php script my command line ignores colours.

For example I use symfony2 framework and when I do `php app/console`, I get all output in white

But when I execute `php app/console --ansi` its all fine and colours are not ignored.

What do I need do to enable colours in my output for each php executable script?

- Note #1: This happens in Centos linux, I think when I was using ubuntu it was fine.
- Note #2: Other commands (non php, like `ls`) outputs colours normally

Comment: As last resort, you can always create good old shell aliases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that colours are checked within symfony2 using posix_isatty function. This function is not available when you dont have php "postix" extension. To install postix extension on Centos I used

```
sudo yum install php-process
```

now you can run app/console (or php app/console) and colours are coming out of the box